# Express form parsing not working

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I've been using Express.js and the `body-parser` module for parsing a form to the server. However, when the content is received, `res.body` it just shows up as an empty object.

app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bp = require("body-parser");

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.use(bp.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index.jade');
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

The form (in Jade):

```
form(method="post", action="/", enctype="application/json")
    input(type="text", name="name", placeholder="input your name")
```

Why is this so and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bodyparser.json()` only parses requests with JSON data. You need to use `bodyparser.urlencoded()`:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
```

`extended: false` means that nested values aren't handled, e.g. `foo[bar]=baz`. You can switch it to true if you want to support nested values.